# Explicit specialization after instantiation error

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I have a template class name Vec3.

this is the code:

```
Vec3.h:

template< typename T >
class Vec3_T
{

public:

    //! internal struct
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            T   x, y, z;
        };
        T _m[3];
    };

    static const Vec3_T<T> ZERO;
};


Vec3.cpp

template<> const Vec3_T<float> Vec3_T<float>::ZERO( 0.f, 0.f, 0.f );
```

When I use XCode5 to compile it, give me a error: Explicit specialization of 'ZERO' after instantiation. but it can be compiled succeed on vs2008. so, how to fix it?

Comment: Maybe this was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774188/explicit-specialization-after-instantiation

Comment: Did you mean `template<> const Vec3_T<float> Vec3_T<float>::ZERO{ 0.f, 0.f, 0.f };`? Or you forgot to add `Vec3_T(T,T,T)` constructor to your code...

Comment: This seems a bug with Xcode itself. Did you find any workaroud ?